# FileFlushBuffer() is so slow

Tags: c++, windows, file-io

We are repeatedly writing (many 1000's of times) to a single large archive file, patching various parts of it.  After each write, we were calling FileFlushBuffer(), but have found this is very, very slow.  If we wait and only call it every now and then (say every 32ish files), things run better, but I don't think this is the correct way of doing this.

Is there any way to not flush the buffer at all until we complete our last patch?  If we take away the call completetly, close() does handle the flush, but then it becomes a huge bottleneck in itself.  Failing that, having it not lock our other threads when it runs would make it less annoying, as we won't be doing any IO read IO on that file outside of the write.  It just feels like the disk system is really getting in the way here.

More Info:
Target file is currently 16Gigs, but is always changing (usually upwards).  We are randomly pinging all over the place in the file for the updates, and it's big enough that we can't cache the whole file.  In terms of fragmentation, who knows.  This is a large database of assets that gets updated frequently, so quite probably.  Not sure of how to make it not fragment.  Again, open to any suggestions.

Comment: What `FlushFileBuffers` does is... flushing the file buffer (and thus killing the usefulness of the write cache). And you are asking how not to flush the buffer... are you jocking? As for the threads issue, the `CloseFile` should block only the current thread.

Comment: It takes as long to write the data to disk as it takes to write the data to disk.

Comment: Do the write offsets always increase or do they bounce around? How big is the file? Is it fragmented?

Comment: And it takes even longer if you continuously flush the buffer, because every disk access operation has a (more or less) fixed overhead, regardless of the size of the data you have to write; if, instead of caching the data and writing it all at once (thus paying this penalty only once) you are continue to make small writes the performance sinks.

Comment: Fair, it takees a ton of time to write a file. just wondering if there was a better system to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the maximum size of the file at the start then this looks like a classic memory mapped file application

edit. (On windows at least) You can't change the size of a memory mapped file while it's mapped. But you can very quickly expand it between opening the file and opening the mapping, simply [SetFilePointer()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365541%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to some large value and [setEndOfFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365531%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You can similarly shrink it after you close the mapping and before you close the file.

You can map a <4Gb view  (or multiple views) into a much larger file and the filesystem cache tends to be efficent with memory mapped files because it's the same mechanism the OS uses for loading programs, so is well tuned. You can let the OS manage when an update occurs or you can force a flush of certain memory ranges.

Comment: Alas, we don't know the size and it can grow or shrink over time as assets change and bugs are fixed.  And those changes can happen often - think of something like a large graphics library that is globbed into a single repository.

Comment: @Michael - then use sqlite, but that probably doesn't help!

Comment: Lol, database did come to mind as well, but this is an inherited system here that I'm trying to make run faster than a speeding slug.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan - with "crammed into a single repository....." I guessed as much! Basically for everything except log files mmap should be a first thought when you need performance.

Comment: Ok, then on to the mmap fun.  Is 16Gigs going to work on 32-bit windows system?

Comment: @MichaelDorgan - yes, another nice feature of mem-map is you can map a <4gb window into a much larger file and move the window to another part of the file instantly. And the FS cache is smart about mem-map.

Comment: Beauty - then this is what I'll go forward with.  Thanks for the help!